# When using Flutter Container, everything ok but no ripple effect - but Ink draws beyond its parent

Tags: flutter, widget, scrollbar, rust-ink

I want to provide a few buttons inside a singlechildscrollview

[image]

```js
Column(
    children: < Widget > [
      SizedBox(height: constraints.maxHeight / 8.0),
      AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
        position: 1,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          child: SlideAnimation(
            verticalOffset: constraints.maxHeight / 10,
            child: FadeInAnimation(
              child: Image.asset('images/mylive.png'),
            ),
          ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            50, 20, 50, constraints.maxHeight / 7),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Wrap(
                  spacing: 25,
                  runSpacing: 25,
                  children: const < Widget > [
                    ButtonCard(
                      name: "My News",
                      imgpath: "open-email.png",
                      count: 0),
```

and this is the build method for the ButtonCard:

```js
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(    <<--->>     Ink(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black38,
              offset: Offset(0, 2),
              blurRadius: 7,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/$imgpath",
                  width: 60,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I use the container in ButtonCard, then everything is okay, but the InkWell does not show the ripple effect (because of the BoxDecation color set)

This results in the following, correct scroll view:
[image]

But when I change the Container to Ink - I get the beautiful ripple effect, which I want to have. But then the following error occurs during scolling:

[image]

As you can see, the Ink with its boxdecoration paints over the parents border. Is this a bug in Ink or does anyone know what the problem is here? Thanks!

Comment: Keep the Container and wrap your ```InkWell``` by ```Material``` ?

Comment: Thanks, but no difference - no visible ripple effect.

Comment: DO you have this tree `Container` -> `Material` -> `InkWell` ?

Answer (score 9):

In General cases:

1. Wrap the `Container` with `Inkwell`
2. Wrap the `Inkwell` with `Material`
3. Show needed color with `Material`
4. Set color to the `Container` as `transparent`

With the above settings, you can have a ripple effect with Inkwell. But very difficult to achieve when you're having gradient colors.

Ref: https://flutteragency.com/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect-in-flutter/

Answer (score 1):

You must have Material -> Inkwell -> Ink