# Ripple effect is not showing on full area

Tags: flutter, dart, ripple-effect, flutter-button

Inkwell Ripple effect is not showing the full area of content. In my scenario, I have a column that contains a container with a color that can't make as transparent after a container there is a simple text widget. I wrapped the inkwell with full content, When I tapped on the content ripple effect showed only the text area, and some transparent area ripple effect not showing on the top container which has height, width, and a specific color. The especially problem is here ripple not showing on the container area. I wanted to show a ripple effect on the full area of content.

There are some solutions to this topic. Here below I have attached some links I've tried their solutions.

[InkWell not showing ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect)

[Inkwell not showing ripple when used with Container decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463515/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-when-used-with-container-decoration)

[When using Flutter Container, everything ok but no ripple effect - but Ink draws beyond its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645233/when-using-flutter-container-everything-ok-but-no-ripple-effect-but-ink-draws)

My code:

```
class LayoutSizeItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const LayoutSizeItem({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            splashColor: Colors.pink,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 80.0,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1.5,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 4.0,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "(1400x1440)\n1:1",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 10.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: My output]

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the `Container` to `Ink`, here is my code.

```
class LayoutSizeItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const LayoutSizeItem({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            splashColor: Colors.pink,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 80.0,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1.5,
                    child: Ink( /// use Ink instead, not Container
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 4.0,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "(1400x1440)\n1:1",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 10.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can remove Material widget that wraps the InkWell widget, too.